# c++ error : <project_name> has triggered a breakpoint

Tags: c++, visual-studio

How to solve this error when i run and close this project?
I wrote a c++ program and it has this error:
has triggered a breakpoint.

```
int num = 0;
string **board = new string*[num];

cin >> num;
system("cls");
for (int i = 0; i < num; i++)
    board[i] = new string[num];

for (int i = 0; i < num; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < num; j++)
        board[i][j]='_';


for (int i = 0; i < num; i++)
{
    if(i!=0)
    cout << endl<< endl<<endl<< endl;
    for (int j = 0; j < num; j++)
        cout << board[i][j]<<"             ";
}




cin.get();
cin.get();
for (int i = 0; i < num; i++)
    delete[] board[i];
delete[] board;
return 0;
```

Comment: Could you post the exact error?

Comment: <project_name> has triggered a breakpoint.

Comment: wntdll.pdb not included

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The statement

`string **board = new string*[num];`

needs to be positioned *after* you read in `cin >> num;`.

Otherwise you're attempting to allocate a zero length array of pointers; that is not well-defined in C++.

Moving on, you might find it simpler to model the *entire* board as a single `std::vector<std::string>` which will simplify considerably the memory management.

Answer (score 1):

```
int num = 0;
cin >> num;
string *board = new string[num]; // here
system("cls");
for (int i = 0; i < num; i++)
    board[i] = string(n,'_');
for (int i = 0; i < num; i++)
{
    if(i!=0)
    cout << endl<< endl<<endl<< endl;
    for (int j = 0; j < num; j++)
        cout << board[i][j]<<"             ";
}
cin.get();
cin.get();

delete[] board;
return 0;
```

> Strings and containers allocate/deallocate automatically. However, a
>   container of pointers doesn't free up what those pointers point to. We
>   have to loop through those to free them.

I have just simplified the code a bit.

Comment: Shouldn't you remove the "inner delete"?

Comment: @Bathsheba.: yike yes..for string it's neing called automatically on each object..